# Create unique linked list nodes/relationships in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm implementing basic visitor metrics tracking in Neo4j (forgive me; I'm new to graph databases in general).  I have three node types: Visitor, Session, and Event.

Every time I create a new Event node, I'd like to also create new Session and/or Visitor nodes, if necessary (nodes with the same IDs do not yet exist).  Here's what I've tried:

```
CREATE UNIQUE
(e:Event { type: 'pageview' })<-[:ACTION]-(s:Session { id: 'ABC'})<-[:SESSION]-(v:Visitor { id: '123' })
RETURN e,s,v;
```

This gives the following error: `Unbound pattern!`, which makes sense, as I haven't explicitly bound anything to a reference node.  However, I'm hoping to write the query in a way that leverages whatever exists in the indexes, and creates whatever is missing.

I'm using version 2.0 (with labels), and have created the following indices:

```
CREATE INDEX on :Session(id);
CREATE INDEX on :Visitor(id);
```

Additionally, I'd like to implement linked lists for the Events in a Session and the Sessions for a Visitor.  Basically, if a preexisting [:ACTION] relationship exists, delete the old relationship and relate the new Event node to the previous Event node (for that same session).  The same goes for Sessions and Visitors with their [:SESSION] relationship, ie:

```
curSession-[:ACTION]->curEvent-[:PREV]->prevEvent...
visitor-[:SESSION]->curSession-[:PREV]->prevSession...
```

I could probably figure out how to do this with multiple queries, but I'm trying to learn how correctly to leverage a graph database structure (and I'm concerned about race conditions).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works as expected:

```
start root=node(0)
create unique root-[:VISITOR]->(v:Visitor { vid: '123' })
create unique v-[:SESSION]->(s:Session { sid: 'ABCD' })
create s-[:EVENT]->(e:Event { type: 'pv' })
with v,s,e
match s-[r1:EVENT]->oldEvent:Event
where not(id(oldEvent) = id(e))
create e-[:NEXT]->oldEvent
delete r1
with v,s
match v-[r2:SESSION]->oldSession:Session
where not(id(oldSession) = id(s))
create s-[:NEXT]->oldSession
delete r2;
```